# When a person intentionally misrepresents items to a self-checkout machine to save money, what crime is being committed?

Tags: united-states

There are plenty of ways that people "trick" self-checkout machines into giving them discounts.  Some popular ways include:

1. When the machine asks what item is being weighed, intentionally choosing a cheaper item.
2. When the machine asks for quantity, intentionally underrepresenting the quantity chosen.
3. Using the barcode of a cheaper item and placing a more expensive item in the basket.
4. Using online applications to generate fraudulent manufacturer discount coupon barcodes, and feed them to the machine as legitimate coupons.

What is the actual crime and/or tort being committed when people do this?

Comment: Have a look at the question "At what point does something become theft". Various US states have different definitions of what shoplifting is, and some are listed in responses there. I think everything you mention will catch you as a shoplifter. Various items on your list will be fraud as well.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, a crime is committed as is a tort. The exact crime would vary from state to state. The most common description of this crime and tort would be "fraud" but the way that criminal conduct is allocated between particular offenses in states varies considerable. Theft (in jurisdictions where it is broadly defined) and shoplifting (in jurisdictions where it is a distinct offense) would be two other plausible offenses.